# Am I supposed to be able hear other champions too?

Tags: league-of-legends

I noticed when playing LoL I don't hear the other champions (on my team) lines. Like when you walk or start to attack they'll talk. I can hear my champion fine, but am I supposed to be able to hear others too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only time you hear other champs is when they use emotes. Other than that you won't hear anything. I would assume the reason for this is to avoid audio clutter. If you could hear everything every champ said it would just result in quite a bit of noise, especially in 5v5 team-fights.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was pretty sure, but I just wanted to double check.

Comment: well you would hear sounds of enemy spells alright ;)

Comment: Note that if you mute anyone you won't be able to hear their emotes, although you can still see the animation.

Comment: beware of the spam amumu laugh emote....

Comment: Actually, the worst laugh emote I've heard is probably Lux... which makes me kind of sad since she's one of my main champions. Ah well.

Comment: As Vogel612 said, you hear the champions spells... for example you can hear Shaco's deceive, thus knowing when to run...